# How to know other installed app package name of an Android Phone

Tags: android, adb, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult, package-name

I have to call an Android app from my application. But I don't know **package name** of the application, I want to call that application via **package name** by using adb command

Comment: Edit your question to update, or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

**Using ADB if the app is already installed**
If the app is already installed on your Fire TV or other Android device, you can run a shell command that lists all the apps, with their package names, that are installed on your device. First, connect to your device via ADB, then run the command `adb shell pm list packages -3 -f`. That will list all the apps you’ve personally installed on the device. If you want to see a list of all the apps, including system apps, then run the command adb shell pm list packages -f instead. Each line of the app list that is displayed will end in the app’s package name. For example, package:/data/app/org.xbmc.kodi-1/base.apk=org.xbmc.kodi is the line for Kodi. The package name should be descriptive enough for you to be able to pick out the app you’re looking for.  thanks for *Elias Saba* [see this tutorial for more clarity](https://www.aftvnews.com/how-to-determine-the-package-name-of-an-android-app/)

Answer (score 0):

`adb shell pm list packages -f`

Lists all installed packages

You can use grep to find specific package

`adb shell pm list packages -f | grep com.android.bluetooth`